# How do I tell which was the original version of Ubuntu installed on a machine?

Tags: upgrade, versions

I've got a few machines which I'm upgrading from version to version for a few years.

I'm curious to find out what was the original version of Ubuntu installed on the machine.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I'm not certain enough for an answer, but /var/log/installer could be a clue.

Comment: I found a lot of info in the /var/log/apt/history.log

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yet another option: by default `/etc/apt/sources.list` contains the name of the CD from which the system was installed:

```
> cat /etc/apt/sources.list|grep cdrom
# deb cdrom:[Kubuntu-KDE4 8.04 _Hardy Heron_ - Release amd64 (20080423)]/ hardy main restricted
```

which even works on a VPS which I'm sure never been actually installed from a cdrom:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 10.04.2 LTS _Lucid Lynx_ - Release i386 (20110211.1)]/ lucid main restricted
```

Of course, `/etc/apt/sources.list` is relatively less hidden than anything in `/var/log/installer`, so chances are it had been edited manually and the cdrom entry was modified/removed.

The same data can be seen in Software Sources dialog:

[image]

Comment: I'm accepting my own answer since the most upvoted one does not seem to work on systems older than 11.04.

Answer (score 19):

Run this command from the terminal:

```
cat /var/log/installer/media-info
```

or, if the file doesn't exist, try:

```
cat /var/log/installer/lsb-release
```

Comment: `cat: /var/log/installer/media-info: No such file or directory` on 10.10.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'll test on my other machines and report. One thing - on this particular machine I needed to run the command with `sudo`

Comment: @Sergey no need to use sudo.

Comment: Works fine on 12.04.

Comment: It appears that this file doesn't exist on older machines - it is missing on two of my machines which initially had 8.04 and 9.10. Also, as @gerrit reports, it is missing in 10.10.

Comment: Works on my machine that originally had 11.10, so it may have been added in 11.04 or 11.10.

Comment: @gerrit try `cat /var/log/installer/lsb-release`. I have an old server that I've upgraded from 8.10, according to that file. I'm guessing they've changed it some time after 8.10.

Comment: @carestad Confirmed, works (as ordinary user even).

Comment: @carestad: Doesn't exist either for me. I think mine was installed circa 2009. `sudo cat /var/log/installer/version` gives the Ubiquity version.

Answer (score 4):

You can see that when you report a bug using `ubuntu-bug`. For instance, you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `ubuntu-bug firefox`. It'll start collecting info about your system which you can review. Among those is "Installation Media", which will show how it was originally installed. Then you just cancel the bug report, of course.

I'm not sure where apport gets this information, so someone will probably post a better answer. But this works, and that counts for something, I guess. :)

Comment: Interestingly, I can't find "Installation Media" in `ubuntu-bug` output on my machine. The only partially-related thing I found is UprgadeStatus: Upgraded to quantal on 2012-10-19 (6 days ago)

Answer (score 1):

A possibly over looked  option here might be to judge age through the use of time stamps. Just look and see what the time stamps are on some of the oldest files. For example, a file with a last modified dated of Jun 2010 may indicate Ubuntu 10.04.

Obviously this isn't a foolproof system, because some files can be copied onto a system with older dates than the existence of the installed Operating System. So you have to use your best judgment.